# How to insert Items from a list into QlistWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I want to insert a list of items into a QlistWidget.
Below is the code i am using:

```
names = ['apple', 'banana', 'Cherry']
for item in names:
   self.listWidget.insertItems(item)
```

But i am having an error that below :

> TypeError: insertItems(self, int, Iterable[str]): argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'str'

Please let me know the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#insertItems):

> [**void QListWidget::insertItems(int row, const QStringList &labels)**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#insertItems)
>
> Inserts items from the list of labels into the list, starting at the
>   given row.

It is observed that the method X needs to have the initial position from where it will be inserted, so when not giving information where you want to add it will show 2 solutions:

add at start:

```
self.listWidget.insertItems(0, names)
```

add it at the end:

```
self.listWidget.insertItems(self.listWidget.count(), names)
```

For the last case it is better to use the [`addItems()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#addItems) method:

```
self.listWidget.addItems(names)
```